# Non editable JTable with existing TableModel

Tags: java, swing

I know I can make JTable not editable by override isCellEditable() function like that:

```
DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel() {
    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
       //all cells false
       return false;
    }
};

table.setModel(tableModel);
```

but I am using someone else's class (which I can't change) that generates TableModel for me.

Is there any other way that I can achieve non-editable JTable ?

**EDIT:**

I want non-editable JTable but I want to keep row selection (highlight whole row)

**EDIT 2:**

This is code that worked for me:

```
table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

for (Class c: Arrays.asList(Object.class, Number.class, Boolean.class)) {
    TableCellEditor ce = table.getDefaultEditor(c);
    if (ce instanceof DefaultCellEditor) {
            ((DefaultCellEditor) ce).setClickCountToStart(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another approach:

- `table.putClientProperty("JTable.autoStartsEdit", Boolean.FALSE)`
- disable a `startEditing` action
- `DefaultCellEditor#setClickCountToStart(Integer.MAX_VALUE)`

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
public class NonEditableButKeepRowSelectionTableTest {
  public JComponent makeUI() {
    String[] columnNames = {"String", "Integer", "Boolean"};
    Object[][] data = {
      {"aaa", 12, true}, {"bbb", 5, false},
      {"CCC", 92, true}, {"DDD", 0, false}
    };
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames) {
      @Override public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
        return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
      }
    };
    JTable table = new JTable(model);
    //table.setEnabled(false);

    table.putClientProperty("JTable.autoStartsEdit", Boolean.FALSE);

    table.getActionMap().put("none", new AbstractAction() {
      @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("dummy");
      }
    });
    table.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("pressed F2"), "none");

    for (Class c: Arrays.asList(Object.class, Number.class, Boolean.class)) {
      //TEST: table.setDefaultEditor(c, null);
      TableCellEditor ce = table.getDefaultEditor(c);
      if (ce instanceof DefaultCellEditor) {
        ((DefaultCellEditor) ce).setClickCountToStart(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
      }
    }
    JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    p.add(new JScrollPane(table));
    return p;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override public void run() {
        createAndShowGUI();
      }
    });
  }
  public static void createAndShowGUI() {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.getContentPane().add(new NonEditableButKeepRowSelectionTableTest().makeUI());
    f.setSize(320, 240);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any other way that I can achieve non-editable JTable ?

Override the `isCellEditable(...) method` of `JTable`:

```
JTable table = new JTable( tableModel )
{
    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column)
    {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: Override the `JTable#isCellEditable(...)` method looks better than the others that I posted.

Answer (score 2):

From the `JTable` [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) it can be seen that there are several methods that can be used to control a table's selection behavior:

```
setCellSelectionEnabled(boolean cellSelectionEnabled);
setColumnSelectionAllowed(boolean val);
setRowSelectionAllowed(boolean rowSelectionAllowed);
```

You can look up the specific descriptions to see if what you want is achieved with any combination of those. From the same API it can also be seen that `JTable` inherits the method

```
setEnabled(boolean enabled);
```

which is described as *Sets whether or not this component is enabled. A component that is enabled may respond to user input, while a component that is not enabled cannot respond to user input. Some components may alter their visual representation when they are disabled in order to provide feedback to the user that they cannot take input.*

Also, if you cannot change the model class, but you are not forced to use the exact model, you might be able to create a new class extending from it that overrides the `isCellEditable` method and set this model to the tables.

Comment: That works. But how can i keep row selection (highlight of whole row)

Comment: Use only table.setColumnSelectionAllowed(false);

Comment: And you used setCellSelectionEnabled(false); and setColumnSelectionAllowed(false)?

Comment: then you could try to get the model of the table with  table.getModel() and cast it to the custom model SomeoneElsesModel model = (SomeoneElsesModel) table.getModel() and see if they have implemented anything useful. Or edit your question with more specific details of what you want.